# Fetching data in sorted form from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php page and have a table named

> computer_complaint

all i want is to fetch data from this table by the latest complaint made by user.
when user files any complaint it stores in this table which gives him a unique

> computer_id

and

> problem_date

is  column which enters the date with time when user made complaint. and same user can made complaint more than once

now i want a query by which i can able to display the latest details of that user's complaint so i need to sort the table on the last problem_date on that computer_id.
My current query is

```
select *,date_format(cc.problem_date,'%d/%m/%Y')as problem_date,ifnull(cc.attended_on,'Pending')as com_status from computer_complaint cc,computer_master cm,computer_st_complaint_mode ccm,computer_company_master cmy WHERE cc.`status`='Active' and cm.`status`='Active' and ccm.`status`='Active' and cmy.`status`='Active' and cc.computer_id=cm.computer_id and cc.method=ccm.comp_mod_id  and cm.company_id=cmy.company_id
```

but it is showing all the records of that particular id while i only want the latest one
Thus i want all computer_id(s) to show only the latest filed complaint not to show all the complaints for each id as this make my display screen wired.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To fetch the last one of each `cc.computer_id`, you can use this:

```
select *,date_format(cc.problem_date,'%d/%m/%Y')as problem_date,ifnull(cc.attended_on,'Pending')as com_status from computer_complaint cc,computer_master cm,computer_st_complaint_mode ccm,computer_company_master cmy WHERE cc.`status`='Active' and cm.`status`='Active' and ccm.`status`='Active' and cmy.`status`='Active' and cc.computer_id=cm.computer_id and cc.method=ccm.comp_mod_id  and cm.company_id=cmy.company_id ORDER BY cc.problem_date DESC GROUP BY cc.computer_id
```

That will give you the latest entry, according to `cc.problem_date`!

Comment: thanks Lars but this query only shows the last record in table i want the last record of each computer_id not only the last entered record in table.

Comment: Please don't say sorry you tried to help me and really thanks for that.

Comment: this is giving the following error

"Error Msg:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY cc.computer_id' at line 1"